# Making visible object hidden and hidden object visible

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function that is supposed to make visible objects hidden and hidden objects visible. since I lack of basic javascript knowlegde, I came here to ask help from you :/ Can someone help me out with my code so that I can learn a little?

```
function DisplayMenu(obj) {
            if (obj.style.visibility == 'visible') {
                obj = document.getElementById(obj);
                obj.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
            else if (obj.style.visibility == 'hidden') {
                obj = document.getElementById(obj);
                obj.style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
        }
```

Comment: there is something wrong with if else part I guess :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define what `obj` is before the `if`:

```
function DisplayMenu(obj) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(obj);
            if (obj.style.visibility == 'visible') {
                obj.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
            else {
                obj.style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
        }
```

EDIT: You could simplify it, you don't need the `else if` just use `else`

Answer (score 2):

And even shorter version which checks for existance of `obj_id` before assignment, so in the case there is no `obj_id` in `DOM` it doesn't trigger exception:

```
function DisplayMenu(obj_id) {
  var obj = document.getElementById(obj_id);
  obj && obj.style.visibility = (obj.style.visibility == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
}
```